# Splitting an array into array of arrays python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I apologize ahead if my question is very basic. I'm still new to python. I have the code snippet where Len(cls) is 27 and I want to split this len=27 array into an array of arrays each of len=3. The code snippet below splits it into an array of shape (9,3) but I would like an array of shape (3,3,3). Is there a way to do this? Thanks

```
new_cls_list=[] 
for j in range(len(cls)):
    new_cls_list_1=[]
    k=0
    while k<len(cls[j]):
        new_cls_list_1.append(cls[j][k:k+3])
        k+=3
    new_cls_list.append(new_cls_list_1)
```

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.reshape`.

Comment: Try `np.reshape(cls, (3,3,3))`

Comment: You can try `[array[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(array), 3)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)